# How to install Facebook Ignited in a codeigniter app?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

Trying to install https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/ into codeigniter.

I'm new to the framework, how should I go about installing this, copying the files into
my project seems a bit heavy handed, is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your installing a Spark (http://getsparks.org/), you'll need to manually copy the files into your project.  The instructions for installation don't list the created/modified files so you'll have to browse through the repository to see which files need to be copied to your project.

Comment: Facebook Ignited is now in [Spark](http://getsparks.org/packages/fb_ignited/show)

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Ignited](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/) has minimum package downloads which include only the files that you need to upgrade Facebook Ignited. You can find them in the [Downloads Page](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/downloads) with the latest version v1.1.2. I haven't created a Spark for it but that may be something worth looking into later on if interest is high enough. Hope that helps!